# Pure Python implementation of a Redis mockup or wrapper around db for unit-testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, redis

Is there a pure Python implementation of a Redis mockup that doesn't use Ctypes like [fakeredis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fakeredis/0.4.2) does?

This is mostly because I develop Python apps on Android (if you look my question on Android Stack Exchange you'll understand why) and need a way to test/emulate Redis functionality without there actually being Redis.

I'd later just adjust to the real bindings when I'm done and upload it to the server and/or Github account where I'd iterate another test just for safety.

Performance, persistence and all the goodies of Redis don't really matter, as I just want to be able to do ex.

`mockredis.do('SET', 'test:1', 'hello world')`

and the mock just store the SET on memory or hard disk to be later retrieved by a

`mockredis.do('GET', 'test:1')`

but nothing more than that.

Otherwise a wrapper around a pure Python db (ex. Sqlite) that acts like a "fake Redis" would be fine too though I didn't find any. Something like [nosqlite](https://code.google.com/p/nosqlite/) but with Redis commands instead of document database's ones.

Finally the short question is:

*Is there a pure Python (no Ctypes) implementation of a Redis mockup, a wrapper around a pure Python db acting like Redis or alternatively a way to wrap the functionality myself on top of Sqlite/Shelve/TinyDB/Buzhug...?*

Answer (score 0):

Someone is working on just this at [locationlabs/mockredis](https://github.com/locationlabs/mockredis) as a drop-in replacement to your Python Redis client.